Can I make my own ride-sharing app without getting sued?
If I wanted to make my own ride-sharing app called 'roll', will i get sued. I'm also trying to create the app from bubble.

It depends entirely on what patents exist, whether they are still in force and whether your app infringes on them. There is no way for us to give you that assessment so your best option is to hire an intellectual property lawyer to do a freedom to operate analysis.
